# Updating all columns of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I am using MS Access to connect to a linked Oracle database. I have table B that pulls only certain columns from table A (in the linked DB).

I am trying to execute a macro that runs Query1 to update table B with the data from A that is constantly changing.

The two are not necessarily related by some ID, so the UPDATE TABLE command doesn't seem logical to me. Should I be using JOIN? I just need a place to launch my query from.

Comment: It's not clear to me how that information must be updated and I'm no DB expert but it sounds like a bad design is in the way.

Comment: How would you join the tables if they are not related? It sounds like the data-transfer process needs to be fleshed out more. There should be one or more clear rules about how data from A should be incorporated into B. E.g. for IDs in B which are also in A UPDATE these columns to the values from A.

Comment: If the table is linked, why do you need to update? A linked table pulls live data.

Comment: That's where I'm a bit stuck. Table A in the database doesn't have any unique identifier, it's just a table that has been aggregating data every couple of minutes for years. I have no control over how that table is structured. I am not sure what options I have.

Comment: I am required to build a button that updates the table I built, B, on command. Table B basically filters out data from A.

Comment: Which records should Table B filter out?

Comment: Dates, prod codes, locations, error codes. Just a bin of data.

Comment: It sounds like Table B is just a "view" on table A. I am not confident that you need an UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it sounds like Table B is simply a "view" on Table A. I am not confident that you need an UPDATE query.

In MS Access, [the syntax to create a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177895%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is thus:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
  SELECT 
    col1, col2 
  FROM 
    [Table A]
```